# Flutter redux dispatch event when widget is created

Tags: redux, flutter

I would like to load data using redux action when the widget is constructed. Let´s say for example:

User opens the app, then the HomeScreen component is rendered, on this page are some categories.

I have achieved to have AppState that supports multiple stores (yet not tested) that is populated with initial data in main() using FlutterStorage.

So in HomeScreen I am able to access data from build() using StoreConnector since in convertor i will get the store, so i can dispatch events or read app state. But this is only inside the build() which is problem, because if dispatch the LoadCategories event in the render method, then it will go into infinite loop.

In reactjs i was able to map dispatch to component (widget) properties so in componentDidMount i was able to fetch data. This seems impossible in Flutter.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but there is an alternative depending on your use case. According to the doc you can use `onInit` or `onInitialBuild`.

[onInit](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_redux/latest/flutter_redux/StoreConnector/onInit.html)

> This can be useful for dispatching actions that fetch data for your Widget when it is first displayed.

[onInitialBuild](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_redux/latest/flutter_redux/StoreConnector/onInitialBuild.html)

> This can be useful for starting certain animations, such as showing Snackbars, after the Widget is built the first time.

Answer (score 14):

Probably not the best answer but I have noticed that StoreConnector has a onInit property which does what I need.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new StoreConnector<AppState, List<Category>>(
    onInit: (store) {
      store.dispatch(LoadCategoriesAction());
    },
    builder: (context, categories) {
```

Comment: this one saved me!